# Apply function to each cell across multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Say that I have N identical (same number of rows and columns) dataframes:

```
set.seed(2)
df1 <- data.frame(replicate(100,rnorm(100)))
df2 <- data.frame(replicate(100,rnorm(100)))
dfN <- data.frame(replicate(100,rnorm(100)))
```

And I want to apply a function (in this case `t.test()`) across *each* "cell" of N dataframes so that what returns is a separate dataframe that contains a t value for each cell test performed. Essentially, I want to take the first cell of each dataframe,

```
one <- df1[1,1]
two <- df2[1,1]
Nth <- dfN[1,1]
```

Perform a `t.test()` on those cells,

```
first.cell.each <- cbind.data.frame(one,two,Nth)
t.test(first.cell.each, mu=0)
```

And repeat that across all cells (in this case 10000).

edit: clarified

Comment: @ZheyuanLi, my apologies, I should have been clearer. Identical in terms of number of rows and columns.

Comment: You are using the wrong data structure. Combine the data.frames into an array and use apply.

Comment: You can now use the new `tidyr` package to combine multiple dataframes and munge their data. See https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a `matrix` to store the output of `p.value` of `t.test` having the same dimensions of the individual datasets.  Then, loop through the sequence of rows and columns, extract the elements from each of the datasets, concatenate, and do the `t.test` and assign the output to the same row/column index of 'res'.

```
res <- matrix(, ncol=100, nrow=100)
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df1))){
 for(j in seq_len(ncol(df1))){
  res[i,j] <- t.test(c(df1[i,j], df2[i,j], dfN[i,j]), mu = 0)$p.value

 }}
```

My code also returns a 100*100 matrix

```
str(res)
#num [1:100, 1:100] 0.629 0.5 0.131 0.769 0.348 ...
```

---

If there are many datasets, we can place it in a `list`, then convert it to an `array` and do the `t.test` using `apply`

```
lst <-  mget(paste0("df", c(1, 2, "N")))
ar1 <- array(unlist(lst), dim = c(dim(df1), length(lst)))
res2 <-  apply(aperm(ar1, c(3, 1, 2)), c(2,3), FUN = function(x) t.test(x, mu = 0)$p.value) 
str(res2)
# num [1:100, 1:100] 0.629 0.5 0.131 0.769 0.348 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have all your data frames saved in a list `datlst`, this does the work

```
z <- matrix(tapply(unlist(datlst, use.names = FALSE),
                   rep(gl(prod(dim(datlst[[1]])), 1), length(datlst)),
                   FUN = function (u) t.test(u, mu = 0)$p.value),
            nrow = nrow(datlst[[1]]))
```

---

With your example data frames `datlst <- list(df1, df2, dfN)`, my code successfully returns you a 100 * 100 matrix:

```
str(z)
# num [1:100, 1:100] 0.629 0.5 0.131 0.769 0.348 ...
```